# Group table in R by ID and sequence without gaps

Tags: r, plyr

I have a table of fictitious hospital data and need to replace the discharge date to the final discharge date when the (non-existing) person has hospital transfers.

```
rows <- sort(c(which(data$TRANSFER_NUM != 0), which(data$TRANSFER_NUM == 1)-1))
subset <- data[rows,]
```

The annoying thing is that some people can have multiple transfers for different events, i.e.

```
 
ID     DISCHARGE_DATE   FILE_SEQUENCE   TRANSFER_NUM
A      1992-12-04       3360            0
A      1993-02-11       3361            1
A      1993-03-10       3362            2
A      1993-11-25       3363            3
B      1987-05-15       3419            0
B      1987-05-19       3420            1
B      1990-02-03       3473            0
B      1990-02-05       3474            1
```

This means that

```
ddply(subset, "ID", mutate, max=max(DISCHARGE_DATE))
```

would bring back the wrong results for person B, while the correct results should be:

```
 
ID     DISCHARGE_DATE   FILE_SEQUENCE   TRANSFER_NUM    NEW_DISCHARGE_DATE
A      1992-12-04       3360            0               1993-11-25 
A      1993-02-11       3361            1               1993-11-25 
A      1993-03-10       3362            2               1993-11-25 
A      1993-11-25       3363            3               1993-11-25 
B      1987-05-15       3419            0               1987-05-19    
B      1987-05-19       3420            1               1987-05-19    
B      1990-02-03       3473            0               1990-02-05
B      1990-02-05       3474            1               1990-02-05
```

I guess some additional grouping might help, perhaps something like:

```
 
ID     DISCHARGE_DATE   FILE_SEQUENCE   TRANSFER_NUM    GROUP    NEW_DISCHARGE_DATE
A      1992-12-04       3360            0               1        1993-11-25 
A      1993-02-11       3361            1               1        1993-11-25 
A      1993-03-10       3362            2               1        1993-11-25 
A      1993-11-25       3363            3               1        1993-11-25 
B      1987-05-15       3419            0               1        1987-05-19    
B      1987-05-19       3420            1               1        1987-05-19    
B      1990-02-03       3473            0               2        1990-02-05
B      1990-02-05       3474            1               2        1990-02-05
```

Any help will be highy appreciated!

Comment: Just a gentle tip:  `data` and `subset` are well-used `R` commands. You might consider not using them as object names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
ddply(subset, .(ID,grp=c(0,cumsum(diff(subset$TRANSFER_NUM)-1))), mutate, max=max(DISCHARGE_DATE))
```

it does assume TRANSFER_NUM is continuous i.e. 1:x

As per comment, this is the result I get:

```
subset<-read.table(text="ID     DISCHARGE_DATE   FILE_SEQUENCE   TRANSFER_NUM
A      1992-12-04       3360            0
A      1993-02-11       3361            1
A      1993-03-10       3362            2
A      1993-11-25       3363            3
B      1987-05-15       3419            0
B      1987-05-19       3420            1
B      1990-02-03       3473            0
B      1990-02-05       3474            1",header=T)

subset$DISCHARGE_DATE<-as.Date(subset$DISCHARGE_DATE)

ddply(subset, .(ID,grp=c(0,cumsum(diff(subset$TRANSFER_NUM)-1))), mutate, max=max(DISCHARGE_DATE))

  grp ID DISCHARGE_DATE FILE_SEQUENCE TRANSFER_NUM        max
1   0  A     1992-12-04          3360            0 1993-11-25
2   0  A     1993-02-11          3361            1 1993-11-25
3   0  A     1993-03-10          3362            2 1993-11-25
4   0  A     1993-11-25          3363            3 1993-11-25
5  -6  B     1990-02-03          3473            0 1990-02-05
6  -6  B     1990-02-05          3474            1 1990-02-05
7  -4  B     1987-05-15          3419            0 1987-05-19
8  -4  B     1987-05-19          3420            1 1987-05-19
```

if the sub-order of grp per ID is the problem, then just change the sign in front of the grp definition:

```
ddply(subset, .(ID,grp=-c(0,cumsum(diff(subset$TRANSFER_NUM)-1))), mutate, max=max(DISCHARGE_DATE))

  grp ID DISCHARGE_DATE FILE_SEQUENCE TRANSFER_NUM        max
1   0  A     1992-12-04          3360            0 1993-11-25
2   0  A     1993-02-11          3361            1 1993-11-25
3   0  A     1993-03-10          3362            2 1993-11-25
4   0  A     1993-11-25          3363            3 1993-11-25
5   4  B     1987-05-15          3419            0 1987-05-19
6   4  B     1987-05-19          3420            1 1987-05-19
7   6  B     1990-02-03          3473            0 1990-02-05
8   6  B     1990-02-05          3474            1 1990-02-05
```

Comment: a very neat version of the above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JoanneDemmler - I've updated the question with my result, which seems to work for both. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: if you are worried about the sub-order of groups in B, just add "-" in front of the grp definition, i.e. grp=-c(0,cumsum(diff(subset$TRANSFER_NUM)-1))

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you need an intermediate grouping column.  Here it is with a nested `ddply`:

```
ddply(
  ddply(df, "ID", mutate, GROUP=cumsum(c(0, diff(TRANSFER_NUM) < 0))),
  c("ID", "GROUP"),
  mutate, DISCHARGE_NEW=max(as.character(DISCHARGE_DATE))
)
#   ID DISCHARGE_DATE FILE_SEQUENCE TRANSFER_NUM GROUP DISCHARGE_NEW
# 1  A     1992-12-04          3360            0     0    1993-11-25
# 2  A     1993-02-11          3361            1     0    1993-11-25
# 3  A     1993-03-10          3362            2     0    1993-11-25
# 4  A     1993-11-25          3363            3     0    1993-11-25
# 5  B     1987-05-15          3419            0     0    1987-05-19
# 6  B     1987-05-19          3420            1     0    1987-05-19
# 7  B     1990-02-03          3473            0     1    1990-02-05
# 8  B     1990-02-05          3474            1     1    1990-02-05
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you very much! I don't think I would have ever thought of the `cumsum(c(0, diff(TRANSFER_NUM) < 0))` bit.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler, I'm working off of the table you posted, sorted as it was.  This needs to be sorted by transfer_num (at least within groups) to work.  Are you sure the `df` you are using is in the same order as what you posted?